# Consider . (dot) when applied to something that is supposed to be run-time polymorphic

Tags: c++

What is the meaning of the following in Bjarne Stroustrup's The C++ Programming Language Fourth Edition?

> "Consider . (dot) suspect when applied to something that is supposed
>   to be run-time polymorphic unless it is obviously applied to a
>   reference."

Comment: It means ["be wary of object slicing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to [object slicing in C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

Say you have

```
struct Base
{
   virtual void print() { std::cout << "In Base::print()\n"; }
};

strut Derived : Base
{
   virtual void print() { std::cout << "In Derived::print()\n"; }
};
```

Now you can use them as:

```
void test(Base base)
{
   base.print();
}

int main()
{
   Derived d;
   test(d);
}
```

When you use it like that, your program suffers from the object slicing problem. `base` in `test` does not retain any information about `Derived`. It has been sliced to be just a `Base`. Hence, the output you will get will correspond to the output of `Base::print()`.

If you use:

```
void test(Base& base)
{
   base.print();
}

int main()
{
   Derived d;
   test(d);
}
```

the program does not suffer from the object slicing problem. It works polymorphically and the output will correspond to the output from `Derived::print()`.

The cautionary note corresponds to use of `base.print()` in the first version of `test`. It uses the `. (dot)` operator on an object that is a polymorphic type, not a reference.